# Is there a way to call a method upon leaving a page with JSF or PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, managed-bean, window.onunload

Is there a way to call a method upon leaving a page with JSF?

Comment: Incidentally, this is mentioned in the JSF 2.2 JSR: *"Event system enhancements. For example, the ability to install a listener for page navigation events. This would enable the familiar dialog, "You have unsaved changes in this page, are you sure you want to discard them?"*

Comment: Possibly the spec intends a server side navigation here, but that would be limiting since the user needs to use postbacks to navigate to a new page then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not when using native JSF or PrimeFaces. Your best bet would be to hook on session expiration instead.

```
import jakarta.inject.Named;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        // Your code here.
    }
}
```

If you happen to use the JSF utility library [OmniFaces](https://omnifaces.org), then you can use its [`@ViewScoped`](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/ViewScoped). This will call the `@PreDestroy` when leaving the page referencing the view scoped bean.

```
import jakarta.inject.Named;
import org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        // Your code here.
    }
}
```

[Under the covers](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/3.13.3/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/omnifaces/unload.unminified.js#L63), it works by triggering a [`navigator.sendBeacon()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) during the window `beforeunload` or `pagehide` event with a fallback to synchronous XHR (which is deprecated in [modern browsers supporting `navigator.sendBeacon()`](https://caniuse.com/#search=beacon)).

#### See also:

- [How detect and remove (during a session) unused @ViewScoped beans that can't be garbage collected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410601/how-detect-and-remove-during-a-session-unused-viewscoped-beans-that-cant-be/)

Answer (score 3):

If you use omnifaces @ViewScoped annotation in the backing bean the bean object is destroyed when you leave the view; so you can call a function when this happens using the @PreDestroy annotation in it.

> **Note**: You must use omnifaces @ViewScoped annotation; with standard JSF @ViewScoped annotation the object isn't destroyed just by leaving
> the view, so pay attention to the import!
>
> **Source:** http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/ViewScoped

Answer (score 2):

Your problem Solution :- it work with java script

```
    <head>
<title>onunload test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onunload = unloadPage;

function unloadPage()
{
 alert("unload event detected!");
}
</script>
</head>
```

Also Some link for more details:-
[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload)

Comment: The OP want to call a JSF backing bean method, not to show a simple alert.

Comment: maybe you can programmatically click a hidden commandButton in the unload event to call a method in backing bean

Comment: @BalusC I don't see OP has written he want to call baking bean method, he want simply to call method, or can't write...

Answer (score 0):

You can call a JSF managed bean method when you are closing the page or navigating to another page by using a `<a4j:jsFunction/>` and calling it at '***onunload***' event of the page body as below.

```
<body onunload="leavingPage()">

<a4j:jsFunction name="leavingPage" action="#{myBean.myMethod}"/>
```

Comment: Have you ever tried it yourself? It won't work. At least, not in normal webbrowsers.

Comment: I dont know what are the "normal webbrowsers". But I have tried this before I put it here. 
Now again I tried it in Chrome, FF and IE. Have YOU tried this before commenting?

Comment: Then you had the luck to be inside a race condition everytime where ajax request has won from the browser close event. This is however **not** guaranteed to be successful everytime. For sure not in production where the server usually runs at a physically different machine and the network latency is thus higher.